# Android SDK configuration

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I made a functional app for Android, but when I copied my source files to new pc and after I installed SDK+Eclipse+ADT, I tried to open my workspace (which worked in the previous pc) I got an error:

> "Unable to resolve target 'Motorola Mobility, Inc.:ICS_R1:15'"

There are also being shown three errors in my `main.java` file:

- The type `android.os.Bundle` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The import `android.content.Intent` cannot be resolved
- The type `android.app.Activity` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: did you try redefining build target and cleaning the project?

Comment: dunno how to do it, can u post me any tutorial plz?

Comment: right click on your project->properties then select Android and select the wanted api (seems like you were using ICS) then apply.. and then try clean your project

Comment: after redefining errors disappeared and just some warnings appeared, that is still better, thx, but what did u mean by clean? fix project properties or anything else?

Comment: good to know that error are gone :) as for cleaning you just go to menu taband select Project->Clean and wait for eclipse to rebuild

Comment: yeah, it works thx again, but this error is still there "Unable to resolve target 'Motorola Mobility, Inc.:ICS_R1:15'" when I start Eclipse

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea about such error :(

Comment: well at least you got your project working again.. I think such problem happened because you copied the entire project directory.. usually when I make such thing I just create a new project then override src and res folders and the manifest file with the old ones.. this will help avoid all problems